# iPad drill down menu

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to build a program which when it opens, has 4 large buttons, each button will take the user down into a sub menu, this sub menu will contain a list of items which is selected the user can view more about and then return to the list of items.  The user can then return back to the main screen.

Which order do I go about doing this? I'm stuck logically at how i'm going to design it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good several reads through the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) may help answer a lot of your questions.  Specifically the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Navigation Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1) should be very helpful in giving you a good idea of both how to begin structuring your application and implementing it.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the links you gave, and I have a better understanding of the MVC, i've redesigned my idea using tab bar controller.